# phpmailer eml file with rfc/822 not opening on outlook but open on gmail

Tags: php, phpmailer, eml

I am implementing some code to send an eml file with `phpmailer`.
When I'm using `mime_type` for eml attachements of rfc/822, it's opening in Gmail but not opening in Outlook. If I change `mime_type` to `application/octet-stream`, it's opening in Outlook but not in Gmail.

```
application/octet-stream -> gmail(not working) outlook(working)
application/vnd.ms-outlook   -> gmail(not working) outlook(working)
application/CDFV2-encrypted -> gmail(not working) outlook(working)
message/rfc822           -> gmail(working) outlook(not working)
```

Comment: Can you provide us what you already tried? Any example code?

Comment: And what do you mean by `It's not opening`?

Comment: `message/rfc822` is the correct MIME type for a message; that means this sounds like a bug in Outlook, which shouldn't come as a surprise. Also, sniffing MIME type from content is a bad idea from a security point of view as it means you can be subject to attacks involving polyglot files.

Comment: Actually for outlook and office365 it gets to 1kb file which is opening blank.